# SQL multiple line count

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to avoid to multiply the number of queries to do several times lines counts in different tables. 
I have one id (from a previous request - ID_roster). With this id I need to check in many tables the number of lines to display badges:

```
// Get number of MEMBERS in the roster  
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_membre) 
                                FROM roster_par_membre 
                                WHERE ID_roster = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_roster);  
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($nombre_membre);
$stmt->fetch();
```

and then (almost the same query for another table)

```
// Get number of pending requests for this roster
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(id_membre) 
                                FROM roster_join_request
                                WHERE ID_roster = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id_roster);  
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($nombre_roster_request);
$stmt->fetch();
```

And so one for 9 tables; it seems rather complicated. Is there a more efficient way to do that?
cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the queries using `union all` or a `cross join`.  For instance:

```
(SELECT 'roster_par_membre' as which, COUNT(id_membre) 
 FROM roster_par_membre 
 WHERE ID_roster = ?
) UNION ALL
(SELECT 'roster_join_request', COUNT(id_membre) 
 FROM roster_join_request
 WHERE ID_roster = ?
)
```

(And so on.)

This will produce one row per table.  The first column is the table name (called `which`) and the second is the count.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can use union all with the table name
Here's a  python code that generate the SQL:

```
TABLES = ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8']
sql = "SELECT %(table_name)s, COUNT(id_membre) FROM %(table_name)s WHERE ID_roster = ?"
 full_sql = '\nUNION ALL\n'.join([sql % {'table_name': t} for t in TABLES])

print full_sql
SELECT t1, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t1 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t2, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t2 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t3, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t3 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t4, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t4 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t5, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t5 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t6, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t6 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t7, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t7 WHERE ID_roster = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT t8, COUNT(id_membre) FROM t8 WHERE ID_roster = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I am not familiar with python. But I will look into it